# Why can't the compiler parse "a as u32 < b" or similar?

Tags: rust, syntax-error

The following code appears to be trivial and unambiguous ([Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=3c2b3f0a0d51d5c06eaf9f2320983ffd&version=undefined)):

```
let a: u16 = 5;
let b: u32 = 10;

let c = a as u32 < b;
```

Yet the compiler (as of 2017-05-30) fails with a syntax error:

```
error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `+`, `,`, `::`, `<`, or `>`, found `;`
 --> src/main.rs:6:25
  |
6 |     let c = a as u32 < b;
  |
```

What is wrong with the compiler?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Note:** The latest Rust compilers now provide a more useful error message ([#42578](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/42578)):

```
error: `<` is interpreted as a start of generic arguments for `u32`, not a comparison
 --> src/main.rs:6:22
  |
6 |     let c = a as u32 < b;
  |             -------- ^ -- interpreted as generic arguments
  |             |        |
  |             |        not interpreted as comparison
  |             help: try comparing the casted value: `(a as u32)`
```

---

This is a known compiler issue ([#22644](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22644)). Simply put, since a type (`u32`) was followed by `<`, the compiler attempted to parse `<` as the beginning of a type parameter list.  Hence, the compiler was expecting something like `u32 < b >`, which would be syntactically valid, even though it doesn't make sense. However, an example that makes perfectly valid Rust is `foo as Rc < fmt::Debug >`, and if the syntax was too eager to make `<` the less-than operator, this one would fail just the same.

Of course, technically there are ways around it: C++ and C# have had the same ambiguity from the beginning, they just happen to have a combination of means to disambiguate these cases:

- different syntax;
- symbol tables at the parser level;
- or some form of look-ahead.

Any of these will either have implications in the complexity of the parser or in the complexity of the language's syntax definition. The inclusion of those mechanisms in Rust could lead to breaking changes in the syntax (or probably just the rustc syntax crate).

As there is currently no active discussion to address this issue, a fairly simple and long-term solution is to wrap the cast around parentheses:

```
let c = (a as u32) < b;
```

Comment: Neither C++ nor C# have that ambiguity, because their syntax for type casting is  `(DATA_TYPE) EXPRESSION` rather than`EXPRESSION as DATA_TYPE`.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick Sure, the syntax for casting avoids the issue. On the other hand, C and C++ require keeping track of symbol tables for other constructs, and C# does token lookahead to clear up any eventual ambiguity (more info [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22644#issuecomment-75466424)). I have updated the answer nevertheless.